# Angular 13+ .NetCore 5 Hosted on IIS But when brows it shows 500 error

Tags: angular, .net-core, iis, cloud, hosting

Angular 13+ .NetCore 5 Hosted on IIS But when brows it shows 500 error

I have tried to change config file Development to production

[image]

Comment: Please install [ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.5-windows-hosting-bundle-installer). Then check it.

Comment: But iis was working fine before and alredy installed hosting bundle

Comment: Please check the EventViewer logs in that server, we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot Method:

Check the EventViewer Logs when you restart the site or application pool.

---

I try to reproduce your issue. Please check below.

[image]

Then I installed ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle, then we can find it in Modules.

[image]

Then the issue can be fixed.

[image]